# How to make bat files for c9.io to start mongod and nodemon

Tags: mongodb, batch-file, cloud9-ide, nodemon

I have a simple .bat file.

```
start F:\MongoDB\bin\mongod --dbpath F:\MongoDB\data
start nodemon server.js
```

This works like a charm when I use it in my computer, but I want it to be executable in Cloud9. 
Is it impossible or i've done whrong?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 workspaces are running a version of [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)) which is a flavour of Linux.

The `.bat` file you're trying to run seems like a Windows Batch file which won't work on Ubuntu. Cloud9 workspaces come installed with [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) and you can create a bash script to perform the same operations on Cloud9 workspaces.

In order to run MongoDB on your Cloud9 workspace, please check out the following [documentation article](https://docs.c9.io/docs/setting-up-mongodb) and to start nodemon, you can just do:

```
nodemon server.js
```